# ActionLink throws wierd exception on call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I came across the following issue:
I have a main simple page on which I want to test a controller action. The controller is in another project but is referenced in my MVC project and also in Web.config namespace region.

The simple page is this:

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Controllers.MyControllers" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <%=Html.ActionLink("Persons", "SearchPersons","Person")%>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The **PersonController** has a methods SearchPersons that returns a View. The **PersonController** is defined in **Controllers** project in the namespace **Controllers.MyControllers**.
When the simple page is loading, it throws the following exception at my Html.ActionLink call:

```
{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String linkText, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String linkText, String actionName, String controllerName)
   at ASP.default_aspx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in d:\Projects\MVC\Default.aspx:line 12


at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Could someone point me to the right direction? Which item is actually null ? Is it a referencing problem (considering is in another project) ?

Thanks in advance,
Tamash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error isn't linked to where you declare your controllers. My supposition is you have a route witch declares a parameter that is not optional nor it has a default value.

Comment: Well, Html.ActionLink has 10 overloads 2 of which differ only by the last parameter : Html.ActionLink (linkName,action,controller) and Html.ActionLink (linkName,action,routeValues). Can it mixup those 2? I want the overload with the last parameter as controller name. Can I enforce that somehow?

Comment: I don't think it's helper problem. The compiler will choose the good overload. Can you show us your routing rules?

Comment: There are the default ones (haven't modified global.asax) :public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

Comment: It should work... I've tested it right now with the same helper and it works. Try a clean project then rebuild

Comment: Same thing. I see now that in my data (in the exception window) says {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} so this isn't for routeValues ?

Comment: Try using the overload with both route values and html attributes